# Create environment for equation LaTex

Tags: latex, environment

I am trying to create a new environment for equations in LaTex. 
This is what I have tried

```
\newenvironment{myeq}
{
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split}
}
{
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{fleqn}
}
```

However, when I try to run the code I get "LaTex Error: \begin{split} ended by \end{myeq}". 
Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your code: the parenthesis in the \begin{split} and \end{split} are swapped.

Moreover, if you desire to use fleqn in just one equation you have to include the package `\usepackage[fleqn]{nccmath}`. There was a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split), where the solution was given: use the package `environ` and write your environment as

```
\NewEnviron{myeq}{%
  \begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
    \begin{equation*} 
      \begin{split}
        % your equation here...
      \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
  \end{fleqn}
}
```

As a further advice, I suggest to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ for LaTeX questions: you may find the answer more quickly than here.

Comment: Glad to help! Please sign the answer as accepted, for future users.